# Difference between OnActionExecuted and OnResultExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between OnActionExecuted and OnResultExecuting? Do they both get fired right after each other once the action has been processed or does something happen in between these two methods. Like the initialisation of the View Engine, ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423955/when-exactly-do-onresultexecuted-and-onresultexecuting-fire

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They have a different context.

`OnActionExecuted` has a [ActionExecutedContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in which you can view the result produced by the action. You can also see whether the action encountered an Exception and see if the exception was handled.

`OnResultExecuting` has a [ResultExecutingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.resultexecutingcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This method gets called just before the `ActionResult` instance is invoked. You can examine the result of the method and possibly cancel the execution of the result. This will usually result in a blank response with status code 200. (you can't do this in the OnActionExecuted method).

Answer (score 7):

From [`ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuting Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuting.aspx)

> Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework **before** the action result executes.

From [`ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

> Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework **after** the action method executes.

Comment: So onresultexecuting and onresultexecuted are actually called before OnActionExecuted? I thought the result got executed after the action method

Answer (score 2):

They are called at different stages of the request as below

- OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext): Just before the action method is called.
- OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext): After the action method is called and before the result is executed (before view render).
- OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext): Just before the result is executed (before view render)
- OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext): After the result is executed (after the view is rendered).

[MSDN Custom Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters#task-1---creating-a-custom-filter-to-catch-a-controllers-request)

Answer (score 1):

They get called after one another.

There can be no initialisation, since the ActionResult you are executing may not be rendering a View - ActionResults are free to do whatever they choose: return JSON, return a File, issue a redirect, etc.

Comment: So when something like a redirect is being returned, the onresultexecuting does not get called?

Comment: If you have code set to run OnActionExecuted, this would run after OnActionExecuted and before OnResultExecuting, right? So not necessarily one right after another.