# Force redirect from attribute in ASP.NET MVC before reach a section from controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Might be a simple question. Please let me show you what is my problem.

I have a custom attribute like

```
public class MyCustomAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
      {
        if(somethingTrue) {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult ( ... );
        }
     }
}
```

and my controller class

```
[MyCustom]
public class ContactController: Controller 
{
    protected override void OnResultExecuting( ResultExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        // so something
    }
}
```

If I put breakpoint to `OnResultExecuting` method, it is reached even I put an attribute in top of controller class.

I expected that won't reach `OnResultExecuting` method from controller because I create a redirection result.

Or is my problem that I don't understand correctly the attribute ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125196/difference-between-onactionexecuted-and-onresultexecuting

Comment: In your test, is `somethingTrue`, `true`?

Comment: Yes, it is true, during debug, the `filterContext.Result` from `OnResultExecuting` has an object of `RedirectToRoute` type

Answer (score 1):

Well i guess you want to skip `OnResultExecuting`  so i would prefer to write below code :-

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {

        if (true)
        {
            //Create your result
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        }
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```