# ASP.Net MVC Action Filter : What is the difference between OnActionExecuting and OnResultExecuting regarding usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I am looking for a comparison between `OnActionExecuting` and `OnResultExecuting`.

When should one work with `OnActionExecuting`, and when with `OnResultExecuting`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125196/difference-between-onactionexecuted-and-onresultexecuting

Comment: `OnActionExecuting` - example usage is when you want to have localization filter (translation).
`OnResultExecuting`- useful for performing logging and output caching (from msdn)

Comment: @MikeDebela one request that if possible please include some relevant link which show me in what kind of situation people use OnResultExecuting and for OnActionExecuting too. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx):

> - Action filters. These implement IActionFilter and wrap the action method execution. The IActionFilter interface declares two methods: OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted. OnActionExecuting runs before the action method. OnActionExecuted runs after the action method and can perform additional processing, such as providing extra data to the action method, inspecting the return value, or canceling execution of the action method.
> - Result filters. These implement IResultFilter and wrap execution of the ActionResult object. IResultFilter declares two methods: OnResultExecuting and OnResultExecuted. OnResultExecuting runs before the ActionResult object is executed. OnResultExecuted runs after the result and can perform additional processing of the result, such as modifying the HTTP response. The OutputCacheAttribute class is one example of a result filter.

In short, these are events from 2 different types of filters that execute at different times.

`IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting` executes *before* the action method does. `IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting` executes *after* the action method returns (i.e. calls `return View()`), but *before* the `ActionResult` executes.

In plain English: `OnActionExecuting` can be used to intervene before the business logic runs. `OnResultExecuting` can be used to intervene after the business logic runs and before the display logic runs.

Comment: any good write up exist which explain the real usage of OnActionExecuting and OnResultExecuting and also show difference in terms of usage and scenario. please tell me a scenario when people has to use OnResultExecuting. thanks