# ActionFilter and ResultFilter different and Examples

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I can't understanding the difference between ActionFilter and ResultFilter. ResultFilter after execution OnActionExecuted method. Could you please explain the main different and example about the ActionFilter and ResultFilter.

Thanks $ Regards,
Manikandan M.

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36099850/5576498

Answer (score 3):

See flow below:

[image]

ActionFilter can be used for additional manipulations on action arguments and results. ResultFilter is processed only if an action was executed with success, and can be used, for example, to modify results which have to be displayed.

Examples you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1